# Wierd mesh deformation ( maybe a Duplicate? )

Tags: armature

I know there is a problem like this somewhere but i dont know what it is called / what to research so i thought i should ask it here . It is obviously a duplication of a question and i will take it down once i get a link / answer

My question is , why is my mesh getting deformed when i apply weights? Normals are correct , i have removed doubles and it works perfect for the upper half of the body.

[image]

Comment: The best way to get an answer to an issue like this is to post a blend file.